# Delphi TMonitor.Wait multi-threading problem

Tags: multithreading, delphi

We have run into this multi-threading problem in our backend services:

In a multi-threading Windows service app, with 30+ threads, problem in **SysUtils.EventCache** arise. The problem is that **NewWaitObj** function sometimes return NIL instead of Event object. This function is used in **TMonitor** sync methods **Wait**. **TMonitor.Wait** stops working when it get NIL for event object. That affects many VCL and RTL thread sync source code and it cause different side problems in multi-threading apps, for example **TThreadedQueue.PopItem** doesnt wait for new item to arrive in Queue and returns immediately with timeout result.

Problem occurs in **NewWaitObj** function:

```
function NewWaitObj: Pointer;
var
  EventItem: PEventItemHolder;
begin
  EventItem := Pop(EventCache);
  if EventItem <> nil then
  begin
    Result := EventItem.Event;
    EventItem.Event := nil;
    Push(EventItemHolders, EventItem);
  end else
    Result := NewSyncWaitObj;
  ResetSyncWaitObj(Result);
end;
```

Looks like **Pop** function is not well protected in heavy multi-threaded app and at some number of concurrent threads it starts to return one and the same **EventItem** instance to two (or more) threads. Then race conditions are happening in **NewWaitObj**:

1. One thread takes **EventItem.Event** and return it as **Result** and zero it with NIL, the racing parallel thread is getting the same **EventItem.Event** but it is already cleared by first thread.
2. That cause one of racing threads to return valid Event handle and the other(s) racing threads return NIL.
3. **TMonitor.Wait** function doesnt work, because it get NIL as Event handle.
4. **TThreadedQueue.PopItem** doesnt wait, other sync methods also doesnt work correctly.

For some reason thread sync in **Pop** method doesnt work when app have many concurrent threads:

```
function Pop(var Stack: PEventItemHolder): PEventItemHolder;
begin
  repeat
    Result := Stack;
    if Result = nil then
      Exit;
  until AtomicCmpExchange(Pointer(Stack), Result.Next, Result) = Result;
end;
```

In test app on 60 test threads problem arise in about 10-20 secs, with 30 threads its much harder to happens, usually 5-10 mins are needed. Once problem occurs - it never stop until restart of App. In test app after thread sync get broken - about one of each 5 operations with **EventCache** return NIL. Looks like something get broken in **AtomicCmpExchange**, I've checked the generated code - it's just one **CMPXCHG** instruction and few more to setup registers. I am not quite sure what cause the problem - can one thread get intervention from other thread for example while it setups registers to call **CMPXCHG** or after the call while it process the results?

Trying to understand what cause the problem, so I can find best workaround. For now I am planning to replace original **NewWaitObj** with my own, which will just call the original version till it return valid object. This problem occurs constantly in our dev, test and prod environments, for real middle-ware services on production servers it's needed few hours (sometimes couple of days) for problem to arise, after that only restart fix the problem.
Test app can be downloaded from issue in Embarcadero JIRA: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-31154

EDIT: TestApp: https://quality.embarcadero.com/secure/attachment/31605/EventCacheBug.zip

Example Delphi source code:

```
unit FormMainEventCacheBugU;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Math, Vcl.StdCtrls;

const
   MaxProducers = 60;

type
  TFormEventCacheBug = class(TForm)
    BtnMaxProducers: TButton;
    BtnRemoveProducer: TButton;
    BtnAddProducer: TButton;
    procedure BtnMaxProducersClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure BtnRemoveProducerClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure BtnAddProducerClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

   TEventEater = class(TThread)
   private
      SleepTime: Integer;
      SMsg, EMsg, NMsg: PChar;
      procedure EatEvent;
   protected
      procedure Execute; override;
   public
      constructor Create;
   end;

var
  FormEventCacheBug: TFormEventCacheBug;
  Producers: array[1..MaxProducers] of TThread;
  ProdCount: Integer;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure AddProducer;
begin
   if ProdCount < MaxProducers then
   begin
      Inc(ProdCount);
      Producers[ProdCount] := TEventEater.Create;
      Producers[ProdCount].FreeOnTerminate := True;
   end;
end;

procedure RemoveProducer;
begin
   if ProdCount > 0 then
   begin
      Producers[ProdCount].Terminate;
      Dec(ProdCount);
   end;
end;

{ TEventEater }

constructor TEventEater.Create;
begin
   inherited Create(False);
   SleepTime := RandomRange(1, 3);
end;

procedure TEventEater.EatEvent;
var
   EventHandle: Pointer;
begin
   //OutputDebugString(SMsg);
   EventHandle := System.MonitorSupport.NewWaitObject;
   try
      if EventHandle = nil then
         OutputDebugString('NIL');
      Sleep(SleepTime);
   finally
      if EventHandle <> nil then
         System.MonitorSupport.FreeWaitObject(EventHandle);
//      OutputDebugString(EMsg);
   end;
end;

procedure TEventEater.Execute;
begin
   SMsg := PChar('S:' + GetCurrentThreadId.ToString);
   EMsg := PChar('E:' + GetCurrentThreadId.ToString);
   NMsg := PChar('NIL:' + GetCurrentThreadId.ToString);
   while not Terminated do
   begin
      EatEvent;
      Sleep(SleepTime);
   end;
end;

procedure TFormEventCacheBug.BtnAddProducerClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
   AddProducer;
end;

procedure TFormEventCacheBug.BtnRemoveProducerClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
   RemoveProducer;
end;

procedure TFormEventCacheBug.BtnMaxProducersClick(Sender: TObject);
var
   i: Integer;
begin
   for i := ProdCount + 1 to MaxProducers do
      AddProducer;
end;

end.
```

Thanks for any ideas,

Comment: We would need to have a [mcve] for this question to become a good fit for the site

Comment: @DavidHeffernan 
https://quality.embarcadero.com/secure/attachment/31605/EventCacheBug.zip

Comment: @MiroslavPenchev: you must include the code in your question, offsite links are not allowed.

Comment: @whosrdaddy Hope that's ok now...

Comment: Why are you calling MonitorSupport functions directly? Isn't that meant for internal use only?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It's not restricted for internal use, but anyway - I made this test/demo app because it demonstrate the exact location of the problem. In our real life systems we work with TThreadedQueue, TMonitor and other multi-threading classes, which internally use these MonitorSupport functions. Described problem cause many of these classes to not work properly.

Comment: Knowing the Delphi version could be useful. `TMonitor` has been plagued with defects over the years. Personally I never use it and I have my own thread safe queue class that serializes using a critical section.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes, you are right, sorry. My tests and prod systems are made with 10.2.2. I've checked the source code of these functions in 10.3.3, but it looks the same. Except TThreadedQueue, we are using Datasnap a lot, actually middle-ware services are Datasnap, and I have seen in source code of Datasnap also rely on TMonitor.Wait.

Comment: This issue was fixed in 10.4.1

Comment: Yes, Embarcadero reported that issue is fixed in 10.4.1, I cant check that for now.

Answer (score 0):

@MiroslavPenchev, thank you for the post!
Working in XE2 and had similar issue.
Delphi 10.4.1 got TMonitor ABA problem solved using the linked list head with a counter and 128-bit Compare Exchange.
Unfortunately this is not an easy option for XE2.

Again, thanks to your suggestion to override some of MonitorSupport methods calling original ones.

The following is the solution that I'm using. It is not 100% perfect as involves locking, but for less concurrent environment it at least makes system stable and free from 100% CPU issue.

```pascal
var
  MonitorSupportFix: TMonitorSupport;
  OldMonitorSupport: PMonitorSupport;
  NewWaitObjCS: TCriticalSection;

function NewWaitObjFix: Pointer;
begin
  if Assigned(NewWaitObjCS) then
    NewWaitObjCS.Enter;
  try
    Result := OldMonitorSupport.NewWaitObject;
  finally
    if Assigned(NewWaitObjCS) then
      NewWaitObjCS.Leave;
  end;
end;

procedure FreeWaitObjFix(WaitObject: Pointer);
begin
  if Assigned(NewWaitObjCS) then
    NewWaitObjCS.Enter;
  try
    OldMonitorSupport.FreeWaitObject(WaitObject);
  finally
    if Assigned(NewWaitObjCS) then
      NewWaitObjCS.Leave;
  end;
end;

procedure InitMonitorSupportFix;
begin
  OldMonitorSupport := System.MonitorSupport;
  MonitorSupportFix := OldMonitorSupport^;
  MonitorSupportFix.NewWaitObject := NewWaitObjFix;
  MonitorSupportFix.FreeWaitObject := FreeWaitObjFix;

  System.MonitorSupport := @MonitorSupportFix;
end;

initialization
  NewWaitObjCS := TCriticalSection.Create;
  InitMonitorSupportFix;
finalization
  FreeAndNil(NewWaitObjCS);
end.
```

Comment: Yes, it is fixed in 10.4 - I checked it. For older versions I was thinking for one more workaround (but never tried it) - to override the monitor support functions and completely ignore internal cache and work directly with Windows API functions for Event creation and destroy. Actually I dont know why Delphi needs this cache, maybe for performance benefits. Never checked what hit will be on performance if completely ignore this cache. Such workaround looks like cleaner for me, but never tried it.